# cronjob calling a php function not responding

Tags: php, cron

I have a Cronjob which calls a php script. The cronjob is executing because I have it set to send me an email when it does. The php script works properly when executed manually. I believe it may have something to do with the permissions, but I am not sure how to check if that's the case. I am using godaddy.

Here is the php script:

```
$dayOfWeek = date('w');

if($dayOfWeek == 1) $xml = file_get_contents('http://xxxxx.com/mon.xml');
if($dayOfWeek == 2) $xml = file_get_contents('http://xxxxx.com/tues.xml');
if($dayOfWeek == 3) $xml = file_get_contents('http://xxxxx.com/wed.xml');
if($dayOfWeek == 4) $xml = file_get_contents('http://xxxxx.com/thurs.xml');
if($dayOfWeek == 5) $xml = file_get_contents('http://xxxxx.com/fri.xml');
if($dayOfWeek == 6) $xml = file_get_contents('http://xxxxx.com/sat.xml');
if($dayOfWeek == 7) $xml = file_get_contents('http://xxxxx.com/sun.xml');

file_put_contents('Bars.xml', $xml);

mysql_connect("xxxx.hostedresource.com", "user", "userpw") or die(mysql_error());   
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET isWorking='0' WHERE isWorking='1'") or die(mysql_error());
```

I am receiving the following error message:

```
   <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(http://xxxxxx.com/fri.xml) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: 
HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
     in <b>/home/content/77/8761477/html/refreshXML.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Run your script as the owner of the cronjob to check for errors: `sudo -u www-data myscript.php`

Comment: How was the cronjob created?  Which user is the cronjob running as?  What errors are you seeing?

Comment: It is probably your include path. you can find an aweful log from looking at the logs

Answer (score 1):

Why it's failing ?
Check on `/var/log/cron` for better error output...

Check if your PHP command is reachable from cronjob. 
I would try to call php as `/usr/bin/php` not only `php` command itself.

Hope it helps

Comment: <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(http://xxxxxx.com/fri.xml) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: 
HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
     in <b>/home/content/77/8761477/html/refreshXML.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />

Comment: Hm... It's not a cronjob error. It's on you php `file_get_contents()` function. Try to make a `curl` into URLs that you are fetching to see if get 403 from any of them!